# Install Apache cxf in karaf

Tags: osgi, cxf, karaf

im having some problems with an sogi-app running on karaf 3.0.8. The app has these dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.2'
  compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:2.15.2'
  compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
 }
```

When I try to deploy it in karaf, it says:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
foobar.it.osgi.status.osgi-status [863]: Unable to resolve 863.1:
missing   requirement [863.1] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.ws.rs)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

I tried this:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.4/xml/feature

feature:install cxf
```

I then get this error:

```
Error executing command: Can't install feature cxf/0.0.0:   
No feature named 'jetty' with version '[7,10)' available
```

Hmm, any tips as to how I may install the proper package? Thanks.

Comment: The complex frameworks (cxf, camel, ..) are having many complex dependenties with specific versions. Karaf itself is an empty container. Maybe you could use the Apache ServiceMix (Karaf with cxf, camel, activemq, ... all installed and working our of box) or some supported bundle (FuseESB, Talend ESB, ...). You could save yourself a lot of hastle and time resolving the proper dependencies.

Comment: Good tip!, works better with ServiceMix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested CXF with karaf 3.0.8. I was able to install version 3.0.4, 3.0.10 and 3.1.6 without any problems.

I am not sure why you get the error as karaf 3.0.8 contains jetty 8. So there should be a valid feature in the range you specified.

In any case I recommend to not install cxf 3.0.4. It is quite outdated as CXF is at version 3.0.10 already in this branch. Generally you should always try to install the latest bugfix version as it might contain important fixes like security issues.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I installed ServiceMix instead and then it seems to work.